# Who was the main antagonist?

Tags: plot-explanation, crisis

In the new TV show Crisis I really didn't understand much of what was happening but I really like it.

But one thing I didn't understand was who was the antagonist.  Who was revealed to be the main antagonist? Was it James Gibson or CIA Director Widener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gibson is the main antagonist as it is also revealed in the last episode that he is the one who poisons the first lady. If you haven't seen the show, you can confirm it from here., This [Wiki Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_%28TV_series%29#Episodes) has all the information including spoilers about the last episode and it will clearly show you who is the main antagonist of this show. 
This show has been cancelled btw.

Comment: @IrrationalPerson You are welcome :)